# .Net Core 3.1 Worker Service use Appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, service-worker

I am trying to get my application settings out of appsettings.json for my worker service (I'm just assuming this is the correct thing to do).  I have only gotten so far but can't actually figure out how to use the appsettings in the Worker.cs

Here is what I have in Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
                {
                    // Configure the app here.
                    config
                        .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHttpClient();
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
```

adding worker class

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private const int ThreadDelay = 5000;

        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly JsonSerializer _serializer;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClient)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _httpClient = httpClient.CreateClient();
            _serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

                var locations = GetLocations(stoppingToken);

                foreach(var item in locations)
                {

                }


                //lets start the thread again in 5 minutes
                await Task.Delay(ThreadDelay, stoppingToken);
            }
        }

        private string GetLocations(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            var result = string.Empty;

            var response = _httpClient.GetAsync($"https://", stoppingToken);


            return result;
        }

        private async Task TriggerPoll(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"https://", stoppingToken);
        }
```

Comment: Could you show the Worker class?

Comment: went ahead and added it @egnomerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have what you need other than requiring an `IConfiguration` instance in your `Worker` constructor so the framework's dependency injection container will provide it.

After the minor changes below, get a value out of appsettings like this: `_configuration["key"]`

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
        private const int ThreadDelay = 5000;

        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly JsonSerializer _serializer;

        public Worker(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Worker> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClient)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _logger = logger;
            _httpClient = httpClient.CreateClient();
            _serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        }

        ...

}
```